# Insert Unique random values without any constraint defined in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to generate unique random customer id values in the first loop, so it's checking if the value of i is less than 0.2, it adds Null to that row if i value > 0.2 then it should add a unique random value which should not be present in that column previously.
I don't want to use UNIQUE or PK constraint to this column as I want to add multiple Null values to it and this is not a PK also. I need an efficient way.
This is something that I have done so far and have failed to achieve what I want. I am new to PostgreSQL so kindly help me out. Thanks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aa_dev.rand_cust(low INT ,high INT)
  RETURNS TABLE (Cust_id  int) AS
$$
declare

i int := 0;
counter int := 0;
rand int := 0;
begin

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aa_dev.Customer;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aa_dev.Customer (
    Cust_id INT
    );

    while counter <= high loop
        rand = floor(random()* (high-low + 1) + low);
        i = random()* (1-0 + 1) + 0;
        if i > 0.2 then
            Insert into aa_dev.Customer (Cust_id) values(rand);
            IF (EXISTS(SELECT rand_cust.Cust_id FROM aa_dev.Customer WHERE rand_cust.Cust_id = rand)) THEN
                UPDATE aa_dev.Customer SET rand_cust.Cust_id = floor(random()* (high-low +1) + low) WHERE rand_cust.Cust_id = rand;
            END IF;
            -- Insert into aa_dev.Customer (Cust_id) values(floor(random()* (high-low + 1) + low))
        else
            Insert into aa_dev.Customer (Cust_id) values(Null);
        end if;
        counter := counter + 1;
    end loop;

    return query
    select *
    from aa_dev.Customer;
end

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from aa_dev.rand_cust(1, 50);
```

Comment: If you want your values to be unique, you should definitely add a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column. This does not require making the column a primary key, or force a `NOT NULL` constraint - you can still insert `NULL` values just fine which are ignored by the unique constraint.

Comment: I want the values to be unique for this step but I want to add repeated values forcefully in the next step, by adding a Unique constraint I will not be able to achieve this. Is there any other solution? @Bergi